# Problems with surviveNavigations option of injectFile method

Tags: apify

I have developed an PuppeteerCrawler act and wanted to inject some common code, used for all pages. I found the Apify.utils.puppeteer.injectFile method, which works fine, if the code is injected by every 'domcontentloaded' event. But I want to inject it only once. For this purpose, there is a 'surviveNavigations' option, which should cause the re-injection for every page.

Unfortunatelly this option doesn't work for me. Please find some test code below, which demonstrates my problem. For the first page the 'testfunction.js' ist found, for the second not.

What is wrong with my code?

Cheers Wolfgang

This is the test crawler, which should open two pages, inject testfunction.js' ONCE and execute it:

```
Apify.main( async () => {

const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
// Please replace urls by existing ones, if necessary!
// See here: '...'
await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: '...'});
await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: '...'});

var isAlreadyInjected;

const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
    requestQueue: requestQueue,
    maxConcurrency: 1,

    gotoFunction: async ({page, request}) => {

        page.on('domcontentloaded', async () => {
            if(! isAlreadyInjected){
                await puppeteer.injectFile(page, 'testinject.js', {surviveNavigations: true} );
                isAlreadyInjected = true;
            }
        });
        return page.goto(request.url, {
            waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
        });

    },

    handlePageFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {

        var finding = await page.evaluate( () => {
            try{
                return testinject();
            } catch(err){
                return `Test inject was NOT found!`;
            }
        });
        log.info(finding + ` (${page.url()})`);

    },

    handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
        log.info( `Failed Request:\t${request.url}` );
    },
});

await crawler.run();
```

});

This is 'testfunction.js' to be injected:

```
testinject = function(){
return 'Test inject: I was found!'
```

};

Comment: I think the other answer I gave you answers this one too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745103/fundamental-questions-about-injectfile/58753812#58753812

Answer (score 0):

You are using a global variable `isAlreadyInjected` therefor only the first request's page gets handled and has the file **testfunction.js** injected, the rest will not.

You can use a local variable and to persist the variable data you can use `userData` ([Custom user data assigned to the request](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/request))