# Fundamental questions about injectFile

Tags: apify

I have some fundamental questions about injectFile:

1. When do you recomment using injectFile(code) instead of page.evaluate(code, ...) to get code into the page to be scraped?
2. What are the differences/advantages/disadvantages in using injectFile(code), for example in performance, anti-scraping-detectability or the like?
3. How should injectFile(code) be implemented, by replacing gotoFunction and implementing page.on('domcontentloaded', ...) event, like I did? Or is there a better way?
4. What is the use-case of the option 'surviveNavigations', if not the one described in my previous post? What is it for?

Best regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the short source code of [`injectFile`](https://github.com/apifytech/apify-js/blob/master/src/puppeteer_utils.js), it uses `page.evaluate` so they are both basically the same.

1) We use almost always `page.evaluate` simply because it is less code. If we need to use some more complex libraries, we use them in the Node.js process (server-side) instead of injecting it into the page. We use the injection only for JQuery.

2) It doesn't matter for performance or anti-scraping.

3) Usually, we inject in `handlePageFunction` but if you need it before navigation, you can inject inside `gotoFunction`.

4) For example if you click on the button, the page can navigate. But for a new page/request, you should inject it again. As I said, unless you use some gigantic library, it doesn't have any performance impact.